# Why does an externally stored blob need a 20 bytes pointer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, blob

In MySQL 5.6, I came across the following:

> For tables created in ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, the values of BLOB, TEXT or VARCHAR columns may be stored fully off-page, depending on their length and the length of the entire row. For columns that are stored off-page, the clustered index record only contains 20-byte pointers to the overflow pages, one per column.

Why does an externally stored blob require a 20-byte pointer? I don't think the address space would be so large.

Comment: It probably includes a filename.

Comment: um, no, probably not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data stored in-row is defined here:

https://github.com/jeremycole/mysql/blob/master/storage/innobase/include/btr0cur.h#L762

And it's written out here:

https://github.com/jeremycole/mysql/blob/master/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.c#L4504

So the fields written are (20 bytes total):

- Space ID (4 bytes): Kind of redundant.
- Page Number (4 bytes): The really important part.
- Page Offset (4 bytes): Offset to the small header which is written within the page, also kind of redundant, since the whole page is taken.
- Data Length (8 bytes): Length of data written externally, in total.

Comment: Given the actual usage of BLOBs in MySQL, I would think this could be reduced to minimally: the bit in the field length (1 bit), a page number for the first external page (4 bytes), the data length (4 bytes, potentially stored as variable-width, but that may complicate things too much). The pages already have a header with prev/next pointers, so they need not store that info in a special blob page header as they seem to be doing.